# Objective-c : Load part of an image file

Tags: objective-c, opengl, core-graphics

I searched in the CG API but i did not found any way to load only a subset of pixels in a given image.

I need to load a really big image in openGL AT RUNTIME (the requirement is that i can't resize it at compile time). The texture size is too big ( > GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE) so i subdivide it in other smaller images so openGL doesn't complains.

Right now this is what i do to load the big image:

```
NSData *texData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:textureFilePath];
UIImage *srcImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:texData];
```

And then i use CG to subdivide the image using CGImageCreateWithImageInRect() ... and its ready to be sent to openGL.

The problem is that on iPod touch the app crashed because its taking too much memory after loading the big image. I would like to load only the pixels of interest without having to create a huge peak of memory, then i can release the memory and load the next chunk that i need. Someone knows if it is possible?

Comment: Why don't you just make a bunch of smaller image files

Comment: I can't say much but its a requirement of the app, i want to know if its technically possible to load a subset of pixels for a given image

Comment: You could load the whole image and create slices of it using Core Graphics. It should be fairly easy.

Comment: Thats exactly what i do and describe in the topic, the app crash because loading the whole image takes to much memory...i need to load only one slice at a time

Comment: I don't think you can load a part of image file. If I have to do that, I will break it into chunk (those chunks can be stored as bytearray) and mapping chunks using hashing.